# How do I enable and use a view mode for a product type?

Tags: 8, commerce

In default commerce2 (drupal 8) I want to add second product-type view mode, to show in views - like teaser version, including add-to-cart btn with variations. I have additional field in Product type Default (in some custom product types too) and I want to limit them in this second view mode.

Seem like Product type (Default and customs) no options to add other view mode and in views is available Default view mode for Product. Product (type) is not listed in Structure > Display modes > Views modes.

### edit:

lamp stack, php-7.0, composer instalation from http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/getting-started/install.html, act as uid 1

admin/commerce/config/product-types/default/edit/display

missing "Custom display settings" above "Save" btn

[image]

admin/structure/display-modes/view

Missing "Product (type?)" in list

[image]

Comment: I was unable to understand the problem that you're having.
You'll have to expand your question with a list of steps you took, and the steps that didn't work. 

Note that I was able to add a view mode without problems, on admin/structure/display-modes/view.

Comment: edited question, I mean that "Product variation types" Default have option "Custom display settings" to enable other view mode, and it is present in list   admin/structure/display-modes/view to add more "view mode", but "Product" itself not. May be I miss something?

Comment: Just bad core UX. Click the blue add button on the top of that page, it will allow you to add view modes for products as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You very much! I added "Summary" and Product is appear in the list now. And THANK YOU for your great work on Commerce!!!

Answer (score 3):

Adding the answer to the question here as provided by [@Bojan Zivanovic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/589/bojan-zivanovic) in a [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225398/how-do-i-enable-and-use-a-view-mode-for-a-product-type#comment275265_225398) above. You can add View modes for products by clicking on the `+ Add view mode` blue button at the top of the page.

[image]